# Not able to pair device to Android Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to pair TI CC2564 module with Android (5.0) and Android (6.0).

**5.0**: It never connects through the device settings. But I can use it from my app with call to function `createRfcommSocket`. Issue here is that I need to connect the device manually every time I reopen the app.

**6.0**: I am able to pair the device through device settings occasionally and it is hit and miss. Once I pair the device it works flawlessly in the app. But if I remove the pairing and try to pair again it doesn't allow me to pair with the following error in Logcat
`Device is not allowed because it is either insecure or of unknown security and needs user confirmation`

Any suggestion regarding how to get the device pair?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. The Bluetooth module's broadcast name is `null` by default, giving it a proper name allows the connection to succeed flawlessly. I am guessing there is some issue with either Android or CC2564 BT stack, which might be causing a crash and hence disconnecting.